# Medial axis(orthogonal skeletonization) of blobs

Tags: image-processing, opencv, medial-axis

I need to obtain something like is shown on these pictures:

[image]
[image]

I think it's relative to medial axis transform, but I need vertical or horizontal lines only.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thinning](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thinning.html) should work, though in standard implementations it's hard to enforce desired directions (vertical or horizontal here).

Comment: Yes, thinning works(I use Zhang-Suen algorithm), but I want to have only horizontal and vertical lines.
I think maybe I must to obtain all posible lines in blob and then to solve some optimisation problem?

Comment: I try to do 

median filtration->otsu threshold->Zhang-Suen thinnning->some filtration of skeleton->straightening of skeleton(fitting connected segments to lines)
but maybe I just need to fit straight lines just in blolbs?

Comment: Your question is an interesting problem. For now I'm sorry not to be of further help. Recasting as an optimization problem might be very expensive.